# Ignore whitespace HTML

Tags: html, css

HTML is not whitespace ignorant.  For example,

```
<div>
    <a class="test">A</a>
    <a class="test">B</a>
<div>
```

with CSS

```
.test
{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:100px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

will result in a space between the two links.  Is there any way to get rid of this (perhaps a CSS property of the wrapping `div`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find a lot of solutions :
http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

To my mind, the best one is to use a `display: block` with `float`.

```
.test {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `font-size` of the parent to `0`, but then you have to reset it on all children.

```
div {
    font-size: 0;
}
.test {
    font-size: 12px;
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:100px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
```